# Java Rich Internet Application

Tags: java, swing, applet

My application starts when we request in browser with http:\[ip address]:[port no] of server where the jars of application is available. A start up page opens in this tab of internet explorer that is static and A new window opens in which we can do everything what the application is for.

Is this a java applet application or java web start application? How can I identify it?

Comment: Open the source of the HTML page and look if there is an `<object>` or `<applet>` tag

Comment: *"Is this a java applet application or java web start application? How can i identify it?"*  What is the actual URL?

Comment: When you close the browser Window, an applet will close, too.

Comment: it's <object> tag. Does it mean that it is java web start application?

Comment: The actual url is http:\\[ip address of server where the client and server object is]:[port no]

Comment: When i am closing the browser window the new window which used for every action perform by my application remains as it is and working fine.